# What is the time complexity of this C++ code

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I am just beginning to learn about time complexities, how do I find the time complexity of the following code

```cpp
vector<int> nums = {3,2,4,5,1,6,7,1,8,2,6,9} //say size n;
int j = 0;
for(int i=n-1;i>j;i--)
{
    if(nums[i]>nums[j])
    {
         swap(nums[i],nums[j]); //simple swap function
         reverse(nums.begin()+j+1,nums.end());  //std::reverse function from STL
         return;
     }
}
```

When considering the loop alone, the time complexity would be O(n). But what about considering the functions inside and the return. I would like to know how it affects the time complexity.
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Whats the value of `j` ?

Comment: @TruthSeeker `j=0`, I have added it. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Why is `j` there when it never changes? What is `n`?

Comment: @underscore_d Actually j takes a value >=0, and 0 in the worst case. The code for that i thought would be unnecessary here. And n is the size of the vector

Answer (score 3):

This is O(N).

- In the ideal case, where every value holds false that `num[i] > num[0]`, the for loop will iterate the sequence, no swaps nor reversal will take place, and you're done. O(N).
- In the case where *any* pairing leads to `num[i] > num[0]` being *true*, you will swap one pair (O(1)), iterate the remaining sequence and reverse them (O(N)), and again, you're done with that hard `return;`.

I.e., this is O(N).

Comment: What if the condition becomes true when i=1, i,e, the last possible value of i. In that case, won't the loop have already O(n) and reverse O(n) so O(n^2) ?

Comment: @Dev5 No. Even in that case it will be O(N). If it reached the `1` index there would be one swap, and a full reversal. I.e. N + (1 + (N-1)) = 2N = O(N).

Comment: Oh okay understood. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The swap function is essentially O(1) as its a set number of operations to swap two indices. The reverse function on the other hand is O(n) as it traverses the entire array to reverse it as shown by the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)

So given that you are reversing your array n times (assuming j can be 0 in for loop), i'd say your complexity comes up to O(n^2)if you didn't have the return statement.

With the return statement, you are not reversing your array in each iteration but only once after which you exit. So O(n)(for loop) + O(n)(reverse) = O(n)

Comment: Does the `return` make any difference?

Comment: @Dev5 It makes a huge difference. The overall algorithm is O(N). In the ideal case, where every value holds false for `num[i] > num[0]` you will have scanned the sequence exactly once, and be done. As soon as ONE value trips the true state of that if-test, you swap numbers, O(1), reverse the remaining sequence (O(N-k), i.e. O(N)), and then return. If the return were *not* there it would be O(N^2), but with it, it will never be more than O(N).

Comment: @WhozCraig could you please explain ?

Comment: This is simply false, because of the `return`

Comment: @Dev5 O(n^2) means if you double the number of elements, the algorithm takes about 4 times as long. O(n) means if you double the number of elements, it takes about twice as long. The reason it's O(n) with the return is because *it does less stuff*

Comment: basically you calculate for worst case scenario which in this case is that the for loop runs completely. The return statement would mean that you would exit once you hit the if condition even once so it would come to O(n) as it wont matter that you ran the whole for loop, you had to reverse the list only once so O(n) + O(n) = O(n)